# 'io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.WindowsFindBy' is deprecated. what is the workaround for this change?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-desktop, appium-java

'io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.WindowsFindBy' is deprecated from java-client 8.6.0. But there is no workaround given in the documentation.